# SQL Server Concatenate results on one line

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to do the following with STUFF but I'm missing something I think.

I have a query which returns results from joined tables in the form

```
DATE       | CLIENT_ID | ITEM_DESC
2017-02-01 | 12        | GLOVES
2017-02-01 | 12        | HAT
2017-02-01 | 12        | SHOES
2017-02-01 | 25        | GLOVES
```

and I want to reduce this by combining the ITEM_DESC into one line:

```
DATE       | CLIENT_ID | ITEM_DESC
2017-02-01 | 12        | GLOVES, HAT, SHOES
2017-02-01 | 25        | GLOVES
```

I'm trying to run a nested query on the returned results:

```
 select [Date] as PurDate, [client_ID], 
 AllDetails =
 STUFF (
  (select ', ' + Details  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '' 
 ) 
from (select...
```

However it's just returning the exact same results. I need to group the first two columns and concatenate only what's common to that combination but that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add group by at the end as below:

```
select [Date] as PurDate, [client_ID], 
 AllDetails =
 STUFF (
  (select ', ' + Details  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '' 
 ) 
from (select...
) a
group by [Date], [Client_Id]
```

Created with your sample data and you can query as below:

```
Select [Date], Client_id, 
    Stuff((Select ','+Item_desc from #alldata where [Date] = a.[Date] and [Client_id] = a.Client_id for xml path('')), 1,1,'')
    from #alldata a
    group by [Date], Client_id
```

Input table:

```
create table #alldata ([Date] date, Client_id int, Item_desc varchar(15))

insert into #alldata([date], Client_id, Item_desc) values
 ('2017-02-01', 12  ,'GLOVES')
,('2017-02-01', 12  ,'HAT')
,('2017-02-01', 12  ,'SHOES')
,('2017-02-01', 25  ,'GLOVES')
```

Output as below:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|    Date    | Client_id |      Item_Desc      |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 2017-02-01 |        12 |  GLOVES, HAT, SHOES |
| 2017-02-01 |        25 |  GLOVES             |
+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: The group by command requires me to group by Details as well as the other two fields and the result is the exact same, the full table with three columns

Comment: Updated query in the answer

Comment: Perfect! I needed the temp table before the select/insert rather than using the results from the select...) as.
Many thanks :)

Comment: I think you can use sub query itself

Comment: If you are using sql server 2017 you can use string_agg which is inbuilt function and performs faster than this approach